# In, Python trying to remove duplicate word in dataframe, but get error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, duplicates

I'm trying to remove a duplicate word in a cell

```
      Current      Desired
0  John and Jane    John and Jane
1  John and John    John
2  John             John
3  Jane and Jane    Jane
```

I have tried the following, desired column gets filled with `o d i c t _ k e y s ( [ ' n a n ' ] )`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

df['Current'] = (df['Desired'].astype(str).str.split()
                              .apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
                              .astype(str).str.join(' '))
```

I have also tried this, but the desired column gets filled with `nan`

```
df['Desired'] = df['Current'].str.replace(r'\b(\w+)(\s+\1)+\b', r'\1')
```

Comment: You seem to have the assignment backwards in the first snippet.

Comment: You don't need all those `.astype(str)` since the values are already strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `split` with `set` then `join` back

```
df['out'] = df.Current.str.split(' and ').map(lambda x : ' and '.join(set(x)))
df
Out[876]: 
         Current            out
0  John and Jane  Jane and John
1  John and John           John
2           John           John
3  Jane and Jane           Jane
```